# ASP.NET Core Identity uses wrong NameClaimType with OpenIdConnect

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I'm using the OpenIdConnect middleware to do authentication with AzureAD. And Identity to handle all these.

In the scaffolded ExternalLogin page I receive a correct SignUpInfo where the principle name is as expected (Fullname). With the default implementation, Identity discard this information and uses the email address as the principle name. The respective principal name (Fullname) gets never persisted.

I've seen that these two uses different NameClaimTypes. But configuring it at AddIdentity(...) or AddOpenIdConnect(...) does not change anything.

How should I handle this?

**Update**

Startup.cs

```
        var authenticationMethods = services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(authenticationScheme, authenicationDisplayName, options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = azureAdOptions.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = azureAdOptions.ClientSecret;
                options.Authority = $"{azureAdOptions.Instance}common/v2.0";
                options.CallbackPath = azureAdOptions.CallbackPath;
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = $"{azureAdOptions.Instance}{azureAdOptions.TenantId}/v2.0",
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                };
                options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                {
                    logger.LogError(context.Failure, "Fehler beim Anmelden via XYZ");

                    context.Response.Redirect("/");
                    context.HandleResponse();

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                azureAdOptions.Scopes.ForEach(options.Scope.Add);
            });

        // Fügt die ASP.NET CORE Identity Middleware hinzu
        services.AddIdentity<TUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<TRole>>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext>();
```

ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs (default scaffolded code)

```
        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor : true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _signInManager.UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync(info);

            _logger.LogInformation("{Name} logged in with {LoginProvider} provider.", info.Principal.Identity.Name, info.LoginProvider);
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
```

Here, the `info.Principal.Identity.Name` represents the readable fullname which has ben derived from the `NameClaimTypes` 'name' from OpenIdConnect. But after the login, the Identity uses 'XML-Namespace' for `NameClaimTypes` and in each Controller the `User.Identity.Name` resolves to the username / email address.

Comment: Could you show us how your custom `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<...,...>` class looks like? How do you generate claims in your `GenerateClaimsAsync(...)` overriden method?